# Catching Exceptions Inside Include/Eval/Require for PHP

Tags: php

If I have an include.php file with the contents of;

```
<?php
    try {
        // something that causes an exception
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        // catch the exception and continue code
    }
    print "Something after Exception caught, but it doesn't print.";
?>
```

And the main PHP file is main.php with;

```
<?php
    include ('include.php');
?>
```

I get an uncaught exception error?

I've tried using eval() as well, but no matter what, I can't get the code to continue inside the included file.  It appears as tho you cannot catch an Exception inside include/eval and continue executing the code you have included.

I can wrap the include/eval in a Try Catch inside the main.php and allow the main.php to continue, but the rest of the php in include.php doesn't evaluate.

Is this not possible?  I have different scenarios of how I want the code to react on the included file.  For example, I'm using Selenuim WebDriver that always errors out with an Exception if the code files halting the script.  So I need to catch the Exceptions to logically continue.  Or is there a better way?

Comment: What sort of "something that causes an exception" are you talking about? Are you talking about fatal parse errors, like invalid code syntax? Are you talking things like division by zero?

Comment: No, not parse errors.  Exceptions from a WebDriver, such as Element Not Found, or Unable to Contact WebDriver, or etc.  The WebDriver always errors out with an Exception.  So if you want to check if an Element exists in the WebDriver, I've always done a Try Catch to check.  Not sure if there was a better way for that and maybe that would help instead.  Lol

Comment: So is it an actual PHP Exception that gets thrown? Errors are something different, although you can get PHP to convert them to Exceptions

Comment: Yes, actual PHP Exception.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException' with message 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"elementid"} when you look for an element in the PHP Webdriver.  I don't know any other way to process a "do this if Element doesn't exist" in a logic form like if else statements.

Comment: What you are trying to do should be perfectly possible, but I can't replicate it; can you provide a real example to demonstrate?

Comment: Unless there is something in your continue code that is also throwing an exception

Comment: I found the problem, I guess since I had to use a namespace in the included content to get the WebDriver to function, I also needed to carry over my "use \Exception" in the included file.  So as now Exception is being used.  So the code executes as expected.  I tested a basic example like I provided and that worked, so I looked at it as it had to be something in my code unique.

Comment: Good to hear that it's resolved

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I guess since I had to use a namespace in the included content to get the WebDriver to function, I also needed to carry over my "use \Exception" in the included file. So as now Exception is being used. So the code executes as expected. I tested a basic example like I provided and that worked, so I looked at it as it had to be something in my code unique.